# os.path.abspath(__file__) shows different path than actual

Tags: python

I am having issue in fetching the correct path of the file using `os.path.abspath(__file__)`.

File: Assessment.py

Actual path: /Users/akshay.dubey/xyz/Assessment.py

python version - 3.7.1

When I am running the script on terminal it shows me a different path, such as `/Users/akshay.dubey/xyz/assignment/dataset/Assessment.py` and there is no file `Assessment.py` there.

Just to add, I have code to change current working directory to `/Users/akshay.dubey/xyz/assignment/dataset` but ideally that should not cause the value for `os.path.abspath(__file__)` to change. And when I remove the cwd it shows the correct value.

Code to reproduce:

```py
import os

print(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
os.chdir('assignment/dataset1/')
print(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

O/P:

```
>>python untitled1.py
/Users/akshay.dubey/xyz/untitled1.py
/Users/akshay.dubey/xyz/assignment/dataset1/untitled1.py
```

Comment: is there a symlink to the file? what does `os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__))` produce? (see [`os.path.realpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath))

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__)) is also giving the wrong path.
I don't see any symlink. Do you know command to see if symlink exists.
what if I moved the file from that location to new one, will it create symlink?

Comment: What exactly `__file__` gives you depends on a lot of factors, in your case it probably just gives "Assessment.py". From the string "Assessment.py" there's *no way* to construct an absolute path in any meaningful way, especially if the CWD doesn't happen to match the directory the file is in. See the duplicate for robust solutions…

Comment: Well, I just created a new file and wrote these 4 lines there. 
It is giving wrong path.


import os


print(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__)))


os.chdir('assignment/dataset1/')


print(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__)))


Output:


>>python untitled1.py


/Users/akshay.dubey/xyz/untitled1.py


/Users/akshay.dubey/xyz/assignment/dataset1/untitled1.py

Comment: Your code would be convincing if it was reproducible; but I can't repro with the program you posted. Again, do you have some symlinks in there? Does removing the `os.path.realpath()` call reveal a different path?